# Excel VBA Regular Expressions Working with Quotes

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I need to declare a string for use as a Regular Expression pattern.

The string is: 
(?<="[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*\d{8}.xml(?=")

Usually to declare a string in VBA for use in Reg Exp you enclose in double quotes so it would look like this:
"(?<="[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*\d{8}.xml(?=")"
but that results in a VBA Compile Error: Expected: end of statement with the [a-zA-Z0-9.-] highlighted.

This:
"(?<="""[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*\d{8}.xml(?=""")"
results in the same error.

This
"(?<=""""[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*\d{8}.xml(?="""")"

works but when I use Msgbox to view the pattern it appears like this:

(?<=""[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*\d{8}.xml(?="")

and therefore won't work correctly in RegEx.

Arghhhh!

Here's the code I'm using for testing:

```
    Sub tester()
        Dim PATH_TO_FILINGS As String
        'PATH_TO_FILINGS = "www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1084869/000110465913082760"
        PATH_TO_FILINGS = "www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1446896/000144689612000023"
        MsgBox GetInstanceDocumentPath(PATH_TO_FILINGS)
    End Sub

    Function GetInstanceDocumentPath(PATH_TO_FILINGS As String)

        'this part launches IE and goes to the correct directory
        If IEbrowser Is Nothing Then
            Set IEbrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
            IEbrowser.Visible = False
        End If

        IEbrowser.Navigate URL:=PATH_TO_FILINGS

        While IEbrowser.Busy Or IEbrowser.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

       'this part starts the regular expression engine and searches for the reg exp pattern (i.e. the file name)
        Dim RE As Object
        Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

        RE.Pattern = "(?<="[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*\d{8}.xml(?=")"   '"\w+(?=-)(-)\d{8}(.xml)"
        MsgBox RE.Pattern
        RE.IgnoreCase = True

        Dim INSTANCEDOCUMENT As Object

        Set INSTANCEDOCUMENT = RE.Execute(IEbrowser.Document.body.innerhtml)

        If INSTANCEDOCUMENT.Count = 1 Then

            GetInstanceDocumentPath = PATH_TO_FILINGS & "/" & INSTANCEDOCUMENT.Item(0)

        End If

    End Function
```

Any thoughts on how to approach this are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
Sub Test()
RealQ = Chr(34)
Pattern = "(?<=" & RealQ & ")[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*\d{8}.xml(?=" & RealQ & ")"
MsgBox Pattern
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Also, VBA doesn't support lookbehind but it does support lookahead. A better reference can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150552/lookbehind-on-regex-for-vba).

Comment: Yup. That passes the correct pattern.  Thanks very much. Note that I had a typo in the code I posted. I had deleted a ) in all the adding and deleting " trying to get this to work.  Should have read: (?<=")[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*\d{8}.xml(?=").   A secondary problem I have is this string works in Rubular (www.rubular.com) but not in VBA.  I get run-time error 5017.  However if I use my previous pattern (which missed identifying a few strings I wanted) which is  \w+(?=-)(-)\d{8}(.xml). It works.   Thoughts?  Does Excel VBA exclude lookforward and lookback commands perhaps?

Comment: @mchac: Edited the above code to include the missing `)`. Also, be sure to check the link provided regarding lookaheads. `VBScript` does not support lookbehind, and this applies to `VBA` as well.

Comment: Ah, sorry BK.  I saw your screen shot and was so pumped up I didn't read on.  Will do that now.

Comment: @mchac: Just added that last line as well so no worries. If you found this answer helpful, kindly mark it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Just did mark as an answer.  Thanks again.  I have limited experience with RegEx and I'm reading through that reference you provided but if you can suggest implementation in my case i would appreciate it.  Happy to post as a new question

Comment: It appears that I don't need the lookbehind though it did give me comfort that i'm looking in the right spot.  Submatches is an interesting concept.  Will read on it.  Thanks for suggesting that post.

Comment: @mchac: `Regex` is not my strong point, even if I use it quite often (pretty basic ones, really). Thanks for accepting the answer and you're welcome as well. ;)