# how to pull exactly 6 continuous figures from string

Tags: excel

Problem: how to pull *exactly* 6 continuous figures from string

Example:

```
f657674
576767g
tt454656y
465767yy
x1234567
1234567x
n645856g
s-5656-54654657657-6576-46567785-4354
pof-user-201734545435454
4545665
345678
f546576767g
rtryty
```

it should give

```
657674
576767
454656
465767
(blank value)
(blank value)
645856
(blank value)
(blank value)
(blank value)
345678
(blank value)
(blank value)
```

What I've tried: (`A1` is the cell of the first string)

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(10^6;MID(A1;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-5));6)+0);"")
```

Then I drag this formula for the other rows and it gives:

```
    657674    (right)
    576767    (right)
    454656    (right)
    465767    (right)
   (blank value)  (right) 
   (blank value)  (right)
    645856    (right)
    657457    (wrong)
    435454    (wrong)
    4545665   (wrong)  
    345678    (right)
    546576767 (wrong)
    (blank value)  (right)
```

Version: Excel 2016

Comment: You may be better off here with VBA

Comment: unfortunately I do not know VBA.

Comment: So, you only want six numbers returned, where there's a letter on either side?

Comment: yes, I want to pull only six CONTINUOUS numbers. so 565dft676 should give a blank value. But st645594uy  should give 645594

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Bruce, but paired down to the minimum

```
Function ContainsSix(ByVal rng As Range) As String
    Dim re As RegExp
    Dim mc As MatchCollection
    Dim CellValue As Variant

    CellValue = rng.Cells(1, 1).Value2
    Set re = New RegExp
    With re
        .Pattern = "(?:\D|^)(\d{6})(?:\D|$)"
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True

        If .Test(CellValue) Then
            Set mc = .Execute(CellValue)
            ContainsSix = mc(0).SubMatches(0)
        End If
    End With
    Set re = Nothing
End Function
```

A description of the regular expression:

- Match expression but don't capture it. [\D|^]

  - Select from 2 alternatives

    - Any character that is not a digit
    - Beginning of line or string
- A numbered capture group. [\d{6}]

  - Any digit, exactly 6 repetitions
- Match expression but don't capture it. [\D|$]

  - Select from 2 alternatives

    - Any character that is not a digit
    - End of line or string

Answer (score 2):

You will likely want a UDF instead of a built-in function.  This should work, but likely needs tweaking.  Your example in your OP returns `345678` as a correct return, but there are no letters on either side. Therefore, I assume you want either: 6 consecutive numbers **on their own**, or 6 consecutive numbers with a letter on both sides.

Add this to the workbook module, and you can call like `=return_numbers(A1)`. You may or may not have to [add the RegEx Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/4650297) to VBEditor.

```
Function return_numbers(ByVal cel As Range) As String
Dim strPattern As String
Dim regEx As New RegExp

strPattern = "[a-z]\d{6}[a-z]"

With regEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = strPattern
End With

Dim matches As Object
Set matches = regEx.Execute(cel)

If Len(cel) = 6 And IsNumeric(cel) Then
    return_numbers = cel.Value
    Set regEx = Nothing
    Exit Function
End If

If matches.Count <> 0 Then
    return_numbers = Mid(matches.Item(0), 2, Len(matches.Item(0)) - 2)
ElseIf matches.Count = 0 Then
    strPattern = "[a-z]{1}\d{6}$"
    regEx.Pattern = strPattern
    Set matches = regEx.Execute(cel)
    If matches.Count <> 0 Then
        return_numbers = Mid(matches.Item(0), 2, Len(matches.Item(0)) - 1)
    ElseIf matches.Count = 0 Then
        strPattern = "^\d{6}[a-z]{1}"
        regEx.Pattern = strPattern
        Set matches = regEx.Execute(cel)
        If matches.Count <> 0 Then
            return_numbers = Mid(matches.Item(0), 1, Len(matches.Item(0)) - 1)
        End If
    End If
End If

Set regEx = Nothing

End Function
```

[image]

<sub>If you're wanting to speed this up, I think if you switch the `If/else` statements, it might run a little quicker since it won't *always* run the Regex, if it finds 6 lonely digits</sub>

Edit: This is rather clunky. I'm sure there's a better regex pattern, so please let me know.

Comment: "Therefore, I assume you want either: 6 consecutive numbers on their own, or 6 consecutive numbers with a letter on both sides." OR it can happen one letter in one of the sides, like f565679  it should give 565679. Or 454656g it should give 454656.

Comment: @graphene - What should it return for `x1234567`? or `1234567x`?

Comment: x1234567? or 1234567x?    In both cases, a blank value.

Comment: @BruceWayne - The following strPattern: `(?<!\d)(\d{6})(?!\d)` would allow you to avoid the `isnumberic` test alltogether

Comment: it throws an error: user-defined type not defined... and points out to Dim regEx As New RegExp. I suppose I need to add the regfex refernce..

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - Thanks! I tried that and get a `#VALUE` return. I suspect using your pattern, I would need to adjust the `matches.Count` part?  I appreciate the regex help, that's one area I'm still pretty new to.

Comment: @graphene - Can you update your OP with the new cases as well? This will need tweaking on the RegEx side.

Comment: done. And really the case x123456 should give 123456 and gives a blank value with your function. If it is x1234567 it should give blank value in this case.

Comment: @BruceWayne - I'm familiar with Regex, but just found out Negative lookbehinds [are not supported by VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150552/lookbehind-on-regex-for-vba#9154601) :(. if you use this pattern: `^([^\d])*?(\d{6})(?=[^\d])` and pull the rightmost 6 characters, you should be ok

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - Hm, I must be missing something. I tried that as the only pattern and the returned values were off...I'll keep whittling down. My edit currently is a mash up of three patterns :P

Answer (score 1):

`=IFERROR(0+MID(A1,MATCH(8,MMULT(ABS(ISNUMBER(0+MID(MID("ζ"&A1&"ζ",ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1)-5)),8),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},1))-{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}),{1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1}),0),6),"")`

Note that if you're not using an English-language-version of Excel then parts of the above may need amending.

Regards